# Ear training - Did I correctly transcribe this harmony?

Tags: harmony, voice, ear-training

(Not exactly sure this belongs here, but I wish there was a [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) stack exchange site for music ..)

I'm training my ear at recognizing and transcribing vocal harmonies (because I like to analyze them later). I was listening to the chorus of [Song 3 by Stone Sour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hzaIHzdZtRY) and I gave it a shot at transcribing the vocal harmonies in the chorus part (from 1:14 to 1:42).

From what I could hear, there was only 2 voicings. This is what I managed to come up with :

***First voicing :***
[image]

***Second voicing :***
[image]

Is this an accurate transcription ? I still find the vocal harmonies very hard to hear in a full mix, so there might be some wrong notes.

Comment: My read of the ["what topics?" page](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is that as asked, the question is off topic. ("and it is not about...transcription of specific works, including identifying notes/chords/meters/other elements in songs".) However, analysis questions are okay. ("If you have a question about...technical analysis of a specific, complete work, or well defined section thereof"." I suggest going ahead with your analysis based on your transcription and then edit this or repost.

Comment: I'm not even sure it can be done, I genuinely don't have a question about theory, I just wanted to know if what I achieved correctly reflects the song. The afterward analysis would be to say "this is a major third, this is an unison, etc.", and there are already other questions on that topic. I'll leave that question for a brief moment, and remove it if no one answers by then, or if it's flagged ..

Answer (score 0):

This music is in Db. C#=Db, D#=Eb, F=F, F#=Gb, G#=Ab

What concerns the rhythm I can't tell you more, but it seems to be ok

Comment: Not really related but I wanted to ask: How could you say this music is in in Db? I ask it because I want to know how to do it myself too! And by Db do you mean is it in key of Db?